# Details about the specification of the function "strcpy'' and possible solution

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I want to copy string from the *line* into *strs*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

#define N 100
void readAndWrite();

int main() {
    readAndWrite();
    return 0;
}

void readAndWrite() {
    fstream in;
    char* strs[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        strs[i] = (char*)calloc(128,sizeof(char));
    }

    in.open("A.in");
    if (!in) {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    char line[128];
    in.getline(line, 128);
    **strcpy(strs[0], line);**
    cout << "line:" << strs[0] << endl;

    int count = 1;
    while (!in.eof()) {
        in.getline(line, 128);
        **strcpy(strs[count++], line);**
        cout << "line:" << strs[count - 1] << endl;
    }
}
```

I got a report that strcpy is unsafe,which shows that

> "strs [0]" may be "0": This does not conform to the specification of
>   the function "strcpy".

how can I make my code work

Comment: C++ has better and safer alternatives for character arrays, collections and manual memory allocation. Read up on std::string and, for example, std::vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to check the return value of `calloc`, that's why the compiler is telling you it might be zero (null), in case there is insufficient memory available to allocate.